# UIViewController not animating smoothly in navigation controller push

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController called StartViewController which has a textview in it. The text view method is called when a url is clicked.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    NSString *str = URL.resourceSpecifier;
    NSInteger length = str.length;

    if (length > 1)
    {
        AViewController *aView = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];

        aView.query = str;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aView animated:YES];

        return NO;
    }
}
```

But when the navigationcontroller gets pushed with a value and animate, it doesn't go smoothly. It goes halfway then it disappers and aView is shown.

Why?

Comment: First of all, the navigation controller isn't being pushed, aView is. When you say "it goes half way", what is "it"? Where are you making aView's view?

Comment: That doesn't depend on what you are doing in the delegate method of `UITextView`. I think, you are doing some costly operations (maybe loading something form internet synchronously?) on `AViewController`'s view lifecycle methods like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` on main thread.

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or the simulator? Could just be the simulator acting slow. Your code looks okay, if it is slow on the device could be something costly happening in the background as mentioned above.

Comment: I'll have to check on what kind of saves I have going in the current view controller. aView is just an empty view with one label that is passed in via a property (query).

Answer (score 0):

Look for problems with AViewController's view.

During push operation StartViewController would slide out to about 60-70% of the screen, at the same time AViewController will slide in at the top of StartViewController.
If AViewController's view has any issues (invalid frame size ?) you won't see the slide in animation.